# How to use DomSanitizer inside a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dom-sanitizer

Hi I´m triyin to build a function to be reusable, and sanitize some content, but I don´t know hoe to call `DomSanitizer` it allways give me the error that is and abstract class. 
Here is my function:

```
export function PostFormat(post){
  let sanitizer: DomSanitizer; // TODO!

  post['title'] = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(post['title']['rendered']);
  post['author'] = post['_embedded']['author'][0];
  post['content'] = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(post['content']['rendered']);
  post['excerpt'] = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(post['excerpt']['rendered']);

  if (post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia']){
    if (post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['media_details']){
      post['featured_image'] = post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['media_details']['sizes'][this.default_size]['source_url'];
    }
  }
  if (post['_embedded']['replies']){
    post['comments'] = post['_embedded']['replies'][0];
  }
  return post;
}
```

Comment: Just wrap your function in a service class, then you can inject the `DomSanitizer` easily. Don't try to work against Angular, it will be much less fun.

Comment: hahaha @GünterZöchbauer thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to use it is add import

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

after that you can use all funcs of sanitizer

```
func trueHTML(post) {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
    post.replace(
      regex,
      match => `<a target="_blank" href="${match}">${match}</a>`
    )
  );
}
```

and add your text like `inner html`

```
<div [innerHtml]="post"></div>
```